# iPhone 6s | Jailbreak broke my phone when i reset it

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, find-my-iphone

Last night i reset my phone through Find My iPhone and its stuck at re-setting my phone and its been doing it for 10 hours now and i'm really confused.

If someone could help me fix this i would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though your option is to put it into DFU mode as outlined [here](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/DFU_Mode) and restore to a currently signed version of iOS through iTunes.